# Angular 2 Animation Error

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I tried to make a simple Animation with Angular:

```
import { Component, animate, trigger, state, style, transition } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('divState', [
      state('normal', style({
        'background-color': 'red',
        transform: 'translateX(0)'
      })),
      state('highlighted', style({
        'background-color': 'blue',
        transform: 'translateX(100px)'
      })),
      transition('normal <=> highlighted', animate(300))
    ])
  ]
})


export class AppComponent {
  private state;

  constructor(){
    this.state = 'normal';
  }

  onAnimate() {
    this.state == 'normal' ? this.state = 'highlighted' : this.state = 'normal';
  }
}
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <button (click)="onAnimate()">Switch</button>
</div>
<div style="height: 20px">
<div 
    style="width: 100px; height: 100px" [@divState]="state">
</div>
```

But if I click on the Button it said:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: onAnimate is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):13)

Does anybody know what is wrong there?

Edit: Button works now, but the animation still fails and the div also not shows up.

Comment: your coding is from angular2 but you are importing file of angular1.x ?

Answer (score 1):

you must import your **state** dependence.

```
import {style,animate,state,keyframes } from '@angular/core';
```

Luck!

Answer (score 0):

It should be as below . use `(click)` instead of (onclick) , because angular 2 will trigger zone() which trigger a change detection on Async implementations (event clicks , XHR , )

```
<div>
    <button (click)="onAnimate()">Switch</button>
</div>
```

Comment: in angular2 it will be `(onclick)`,

Comment: @PardeepJain in angular 2 its  (click) .

Comment: misunderstood with javascript and angular2 here, my mistake.

Comment: @PardeepJain happens :)  , no problem

Answer (score 0):

You should use event binding here:

```
<button (click)="onAnimate()">Switch</button>
```

Check tutorial for more details about event binding: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html